# Capture screenshot of macOS window

Tags: objective-c, swift, macos, screenshot

*Note: this question is intentionally very general (e.g. both Objective-C and Swift code examples are requested), as it is intended to document how to capture a window screenshot on macOS as accessibly as possible.*

I want to capture a screenshot of a macOS window in Objective-C/Swift code. I know this is possible because of the multitude of ways to take a screenshot on macOS (⇧⌘4, the Grab utility, `screencapture` on the command line, …), but I’m not sure how to do it in my own code. Ideally, I’d be able to specify a window of a particular application, and then capture it in an `NSImage` or `CGImage` that I could then process and display to the user or store in a file.

Answer (score 43):

Screen capture on macOS is possible through [Quartz Window Services](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/quartz_window_services), a facility of the Core Graphics framework. Our key function here is `CGWindowListCreateImage`, which “returns a composite image based on a dynamically generated list of windows,” or, in other words, finds windows based on specified criteria and creates an image with the contents of each. Perfect! Its declaration is as follows:

```
CGImageRef CGWindowListCreateImage(CGRect screenBounds, 
                                   CGWindowListOption listOption, 
                                   CGWindowID windowID, 
                                   CGWindowImageOption imageOption);
```

So, in order to capture one specific window on the screen, we’ll need its window ID (`CGWindowID`). To go about retrieving that, we’ll first need a list of all of the windows available on the system. We get that through [`CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/1455137-cgwindowlistcopywindowinfo?language=objc), which takes `CGWindowListOption`s and a corresponding `CGWindowID` that, together, select which windows to include in the resulting list. To get **ALL the windows**, we specify `kCGWindowListOptionAll`, and `kCGNullWindowID`, respectively. Also, if you haven’t figured it out already, this is a C API, so we’ll use a bridging cast to work with the friendlier Objective-C containers rather than the Core Foundation ones.

**Objective-C:**

```
NSArray<NSDictionary*> *windowInfoList = (__bridge_transfer id)
    CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo(kCGWindowListOptionAll, kCGNullWindowID);
```

**Swift:**

```
let windowInfoList = CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo(.optionAll, kCGNullWindowID)!
    as NSArray
```

From here, we need to filter our `windowInfoList` down to the specific window that we want. Chances are we want to filter first by application. To do that, we’ll need the process ID of our application of choice. We can use `NSRunningApplication` to accomplish this:

**Objective-C:**

```
NSArray<NSRunningApplication*> *apps = 
    [NSRunningApplication runningApplicationsWithBundleIdentifier:
        /* Bundle ID of the application, e.g.: */ @"com.apple.Safari"];
if (apps.count == 0) {
    // Application is not currently running
    puts("The application is not running");
    return; // Or whatever
}
pid_t appPID = apps[0].processIdentifier;
```

**Swift:**

```
let apps = NSRunningApplication.runningApplications(withBundleIdentifier:
    /* Bundle ID of the application, e.g.: */ "com.apple.Safari")
if apps.isEmpty {
    // Application is not currently running
    print("The application is not running")
    return // Or whatever
}
let appPID = apps[0].processIdentifier
```

With `appPID` in hand, we can now go ahead and filter down our window info list to only windows with a matching owner PID:

**Objective-C:**

```
NSMutableArray<NSDictionary*> *appWindowsInfoList = [NSMutableArray new];
for (NSDictionary *info in windowInfoList) {
    if ([info[(__bridge NSString *)kCGWindowOwnerPID] integerValue] == appPID) {
        [appWindowsInfoList addObject:info];
    }
}
```

**Swift:**

```
var appWindowsInfoList = [NSDictionary]()
for info_ in windowInfoList {
    let info = info_ as! NSDictionary
    if (info[kCGWindowOwnerPID as NSString] as! NSNumber).intValue == appPID {
        appWindowsInfoList.append(info)
    }
}
```

We could have done additional filtering above by testing other keys of the info dictionary—for example, by name (`kCGWindowName`), or by whether the window is on-screen (`kCGWindowIsOnscreen`)—but for now, we’ll just take the first window in the list:

**Objective-C:**

```
NSDictionary *appWindowInfo = appWindowsInfoList[0];
CGWindowID windowID = [appWindowInfo[(__bridge NSString *)kCGWindowNumber] unsignedIntValue];
```

**Swift**:

```
let appWindowInfo: NSDictionary = appWindowsInfoList[0];
let windowID: CGWindowID = (appWindowInfo[kCGWindowNumber as NSString] as! NSNumber).uint32Value
```

And we have our window ID! Now, what else did we need for that call again?

> ```
> CGImageRef CGWindowListCreateImage(CGRect screenBounds, 
>                                    CGWindowListOption listOption, 
>                                    CGWindowID windowID, 
>                                    CGWindowImageOption imageOption);
> ```

First, we need a `screenBounds` to capture. According to [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/1454852-cgwindowlistcreateimage?language=objc), we can specify `CGRectNull` for this parameter to enclose all specified windows as tightly as possible. Works for me.

Second, we have to specify how we want to select our windows with `listOption`. We actually used one of these earlier, in our call to `CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo`, but there we wanted all the windows on the system; here, we only want one, so we’ll specify `kCGWindowListOptionIncludingWindow`, which, contrary to [its documentation page](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgwindowlistoption/kcgwindowlistoptionincludingwindow?language=objc), *is* meaningful on its own for `CGWindowListCreateImage` in that it specifies the window we pass, and *only* the window we pass.

Third, we pass our `windowID` as the window we want captured.

Fourth and finally, we can specify `CGWindowImageOption`s with the `imageOption` parameter. These affect the appearance of the resulting image; you can combine them through bitwise OR. The full list is [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/quartz_window_services/window_image_types?language=objc), but common ones include either `kCGWindowImageDefault`, which captures the window's contents along with its frame and shadow, or `kCGWindowImageBoundsIgnoreFraming`, which captures only the content, and `kCGWindowImageBestResolution`, which captures the window's content at the best resolution available, regardless of actual size (and, depending on the window, may be considerably large), or `kCGWindowImageNominalResolution`, which captures the window at its current size on the screen. Here, I’ve gone with `kCGWindowImageBoundsIgnoreFraming` and `kCGWindowImageNominalResolution` to capture only the content at the same size as on the screen.

Aaand, drumroll please:

**Objective-C:**

```
CGImageRef windowImage =
    CGWindowListCreateImage(CGRectNull, kCGWindowListOptionIncludingWindow,
                            windowID, kCGWindowImageBoundsIgnoreFraming|
                            kCGWindowImageNominalResolution);
// NOTE: windowImage may be NULL if the capture failed
```

**Swift:**

```
let windowImage: CGImage? =
    CGWindowListCreateImage(.null, .optionIncludingWindow, windowID,
                            [.boundsIgnoreFraming, .nominalResolution])
```

Comment: It's a very useful answer, thanks a lot. But how to get window ID from the `viewDidAppear` method in ViewController? I tried `view.window?.windowNumber`, but it's not the global window number assigned by the window server.

Comment: @Kevin A good chunk of the answer is dedicated to finding the window ID using `CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo`; did you try those instructions?

Comment: I solved my problem by using `CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo` to find the window 
 info list and filter the list by the current process ID got from `ProcessInfo().processIdentifier`.

Comment: In my Objective-C program, I seemed to be getting a valid (non-0) window ID values, but trying to capture the window image kept coming back with nothing. I was able to fix this by substituting `kCGWindowListOptionOnScreenOnly` for `kCGWindowListOptionAll`.

Comment: A good answer, but if the window is partially out of the screen then only visible part of it will be captured. Whereas the screen capture utility can make a screenshot of a window which is partially out of the screen.

Comment: Dope guide! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here's the Objective C code without all the exposition, and no need to know your bundle ID ahead of time:

```
int processID = [[NSProcessInfo processInfo] processIdentifier];
NSArray<NSDictionary*>* windowInfoList = (__bridge_transfer id) CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo(kCGWindowListOptionOnScreenOnly, kCGNullWindowID);
int windowID = -1;
for (NSDictionary* info in windowInfoList) {
    int thisProcess = [info[(__bridge NSString *)kCGWindowOwnerPID] integerValue];
    if (thisProcess == processID) {
        windowID = [info[(__bridge NSString *)kCGWindowNumber] integerValue];
        break;
        }
    }

CGImageRef screenCG = nil;
if (windowID != -1)
    screenCG = CGWindowListCreateImage(CGRectNull, kCGWindowListOptionIncludingWindow, windowID, kCGWindowImageBoundsIgnoreFraming);
```